# How to save new Django database entries to JSON?

Tags: json, django, database, git, sqlite

The git repo for my Django app includes several .tsv files which contain the initial entries to populate my app's database. During app setup, these items are imported into the app's SQLite database. The SQLite database is not stored in the app's git repo.

During normal app usage, I plan to add more items to the database by using the admin panel. However I also want to get these entries saved as fixtures in the app repo. I was thinking that a JSON file might be ideal for this purpose, since it is text-based and so will work with the git version control. These files would then become more fixtures for the app, which would be imported upon initial configuration.

How can I configure my app so that any time I add new entries to the Admin panel, a copy of that entry is saved in a JSON file as well?

I know that you can use the `manage.py dumpdata` command to dump the entire database to JSON, but I do not want the *entire* database, I just want JSON for new entries of specific database tables/models.

I was thinking that I could try to hack the [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method on the model to try and write a JSON representation of the item to file, but I am not sure if this is ideal.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe you are looking for specific database entries created or updated each time. Have you looked at the dumpdata options, where u can specify app name and model name to get JSON dumps only for those specific models. The you can chose only the model you updated and get the JSON for that. Here is the link in Django Docs - [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding `save` method for something that can go wrong or that can take more than it should is not recommended. You usually override `save` when changes are simple and important.

You can use signals but in your case it's too much work. You can instead write a function to do this for you but still not exactly after you saved the data to database. You can do it right away but it's too much process unless it's so important for your file to be updated.

I recommend using something like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to run a function in the background separated from all of your django functions. You can call it on every data update or each hour for example and edit your backup file. You can even create a table to monitor the update process.

Which solution is the best is highly depended you and how important the data is. And keep in mind that editing a file can be a heavy process too so creating a backup like everyday might be a better idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into Celery. However, I am not sure how I would call a task on every data update. Wouldnt that still require adding a task to the model's `save` method?

Comment: You can use signals instead. In general try not to override `save` method unless you have to.